Decrypt PPPoE password of Huawei ONT HG8145V5 with partial access to the web ui
I'm trying to get my PPPoE password from my router but as I have partial/locked down configuration Ui I cant download the configuration file from my router. Is it possible to get the password decrypted from the hash I get from just changing the password field to plain text by right-clicking and inspecting its properties ?
This the text I get when I do this :  edd47ac152ff0f979aa4eabd19239fe680b42f6550c0e367c282b08d7400cbd2
Or is there a way I can still download the config file with the locked down ui ?
